# Remove TextView after displaying a message

Tags: android, listview, textview

After I press a button, a query is performed and data is returned if data is present or no data is returned. This data is then sent to my listview.
 If there are results in the query, everyting is working as expected. If no data is returned, I have a clause so that an `TextView` is created and a message is presented to the user.

Imagine I perform a query wen I press the button and no data is returned. My message is presented to the user as expected. If then I perform a query that returns some data, the message disappears and the listview is populated as expected.
 Now imagine that after the first query with no data (the message is presented to the user) I perform another another query that still returns no data. Message is presented (probably it's presented "above" the previous one) and if I now perform a query with data, my listview is populated but the message is still there.

Can someone explain me why is this happening and what can I do to, after a query with results, all previous no result messages disappear and the listview "alone"?

This is my code:

```
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //GETS THE DATA

            ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            MySimpleAdapt arrayListAdapter = new MySimpleAdapt(Search.this, allData);
            listContent.setAdapter(arrayListAdapter);

            if (allData.size() == 0) {
                TextView emptyView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                emptyView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                emptyView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                emptyView.setText(R.string.notFound);
                emptyView.setPadding(4, 30, 4, 30);
                emptyView.setTextSize(30);
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                emptyView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                if (getListView().getParent() != null) {
                    ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView);
                }
                getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am not sure why you have `if (getListView().getParent() != null) {  ((ViewGroup) getListView().getParent()).addView(emptyView); }`. What purpose does it serve for you?

Comment: Hi. If thats not there there, the textview is not even shown

Comment: You don't need to check `if (allData.size() == 0)` every time the `searchButton` is clicked. As anton suggested, create emptyView once outside the OnClickListener. In your `onClick()` method, all you need is: `ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list); MySimpleAdapt arrayListAdapter = new MySimpleAdapt(Search.this, allData); listContent.setAdapter(arrayListAdapter); getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);`. By using `setEmptyView(View)`, you can leave the check(allData.size() == 0) to ListView. When `allData` will be empty, `emptyView` will be shown by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create your TextView each time you hit a situation when there is no data. 
Store it as a member in your class and initialize only once

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your TextView in your XML layout, with your text styled as you want, and set the `visibility` attribute to `gone`: `android:visibility="gone"`

To get it back programmatically : `textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

To hide it again : `textView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`

Comment: Ok. That is one way to proceed. Since I managed to get it to work following Anton suggestion, I did not try this. Nevertheless many thanks